# Validar acentos en evento setOnKeyTyped, JAVAFX

Tags: netbeans, javafx

Estoy haciendo un formulario donde se piden los datos del usuario, el CURP por defecto es de 18 caracteres y no permite acentos ni caracteres especiales, estoy utilizando el evento setOnKeyTyped para validar todas esas restricciones usando el `.Consume()`, hasta el momento llevo esto:

```
txtCurp.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
           @Override
           public void handle(KeyEvent event){
               char letra = event.getCharacter().charAt(0);
               String tamano = txtCurp.getText();

               if(Character.isWhitespace(letra) || tamano.length() > 17){
                  event.consume();
               }
           }
        });
```

Falta validar los acentos y caracteres especiales, si existe otra manera más sencilla o que sea más adecuada a lo que necesito  sería mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que no intentas con una expresión regular, para el curp pudieras utilizar:

```
/[A-Z]{4}\d{6}[HM][A-Z]{2}[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9][0-9]/
```